# Logging/find error in .sh script

Tags: logging, sh, error-logging

I have basic .sh script to making night backups. The whole code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`

tar czfP /var/www/backup/$DATE.tar.gz `find /var/www/web -type d | grep -E '/var/www/web/web[0-9]+/web' | grep -v 'web1'`
```

It makes me `$DATE.tar.gz` file of all webs exclude "web1". It works correctly, till today.

When I execute this script manually in console (not using cron), I see any warnings (`"No such file or directory"`, typically when dirname/filename has a space in name). It's okay, I can do nothing with that, clients create files themselves. These files are out of backup, I think.

But today, the script run ends in 1/3 with error message `Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`. I don't know where the script failes, so...

Is there any way how to write the "path/filename" of last error file (causing `"Exiting with failure status due to previous errors"`) into log? If possible, we can exclude "No such file or directory" errors, they will be there daily with no chance to repair filenames.

Thanks

PS:
I've read this error message can be caused by invalid user permissions. If so, I can check permissions but I need to know where the script fails. Till now it was really working correctly, cca 3 years ago, all files are created by CMS (the same www user), nothing is uploaded manually.

Answer (score 0):

The output from `find` is tokenized by the shell, which means any file name with whitespace in it will be broken up into parts (multiple apparent file names, none of which are likely to exist).  Basically, don't use backticks (or more generally [command substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)) where the output is a list of file names.

Depending on your precise requirements, the workaround could be really easy.

```
tar czfP /var/www/backup/$DATE.tar.gz /var/www/web/www[02-9]/web
```

will archive `web0` and `web2` through `web9`.  If that's all you need, you are done already.  You can extend to single and double digits without much loss of legibility:

```
tar czfP /var/www/backup/$DATE.tar.gz /var/www/web/www[02-9]/web /var/www/web/www[02-9][0-9]/web
```

etc (and if your shell is Bash, this can be abbreviated with braces) but for multiple digits or more complex directory hierarchies, maybe that's not what you really want.

More generally, you might want to explore the `--exclude` option of GNU `tar`.

Even more generally, if you have GNU `find`, you can make it produce output where path names are separated by null bytes instead of newlines.  This makes the output unambiguous (null is the only character which can never occur in a file name) and robust.

```
find /var/www/web/www[0-9]/web -type d -path web1/web -prune -o -print0 |
xargs -r0 tar czfP /var/www/backup/"$DATE".tar.gz
```

The `-print0` option and the corresponding `xargs -0` option are a GNU extension.  Without them, it is next to impossible to robustly handle arbitrary file names, so I suggest you install the GNU version if you are stuck on an architecture which doesn't provide it out of the box.

As for capturing the `tar` errors, I would suggest you redirect error output to a file so that you can review it at your leisure.

Comment: HI @Triple, thx for your answer. "As for capturing the tar errors, I would suggest you redirect error output to a file so that you can review it at your leisure." - it's probably what I'm looking to, canyou please tell me how? I found 2>file.log, but it isn't work for me. The rest of script I don't wont to chance, I don't understand it and I'm glad it worked till now :-) I think it's better to remove/fix the file which cause the error end ending of script.

Comment: It's broken, you need to change it.  It's not clear how `2>file.log` is "not working"; can you elaborate?

Comment: sorry, I really don't know how it works :-(, I'm front-end developer. I found eg. https://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/unix_course/intro-69.html (and others, telling the some), I tried `tar czfP ... | grep -v 'web1' 2>file.log` to catch error into existing file.log. The script do nothing (I didn't see tar.gz file in my server). I mean there isn;t problem in the regex or choosing all and then removing 'web1' - it worked till now, but your solution is maybe better. Now I need to find which file/dir makes the problem

Comment: `grep` reads standard input, you need to redirect before grepping.  But discarding all other error messages is incredibly ill-advised.  Save it all to a file and then `grep` that file afterwards.

Comment: "But discarding all other error messages is incredibly ill-advised." OK, I agree with you. "Save it all to a file and then grep that file afterwards." - really think it's the best way, but really don't know how to do it :-( Can you please specify this, ideally in code above? Thx.

Comment: You mean tar czfP /var/www/backup/$DATE.tar.gz 2>file.log `find /var/www/web -type d | grep -E '/var/www/web/web[0-9]+/web' | grep -v 'web1'` where I create 'file.log' before?

Comment: No need to create the file first. You still want to fix the `find` as outlined in my answer, if only to reduce the number of needless errors.